# how start automatically database derby db

Tags: java, derby, javadb

I am writing a Java application using NetBeans. It uses derby db as a database. I am able to start the database and connect it to my application using `start servers` in NetBeans and it works fine inside NetBeans.

But when I try to start the program from jar it does not connect to the database. Is there a way to make the database start automatically when the program starts from jar?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, because the database server is a separate process than the process running your application.

Perhaps, instead of the client-server configuration, you would be more comfortable with the embedded Derby configuration, in which there is no separate server process to start or stop.

The limitation of the embedded configuration is that (a) your application is the only one that can be accessing the database at that time, and (b) your application must be on the same machine as the database.

Here's some more information about the differences between the two configurations: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/cgsquck70629.html